# Display all data when Date Range inputs are null

Tags: php, html, sql, datagrid, jquery-easyui

I have a Datagrid with a date range filter implemented, in wich I have two date inputs, one for the 'fromDate' parameter and other for 'toDate' parameter, this allows me to display the data between both dates.

I would like to display all my data before applying any filters. The datagrid only allows me to display data when I apply the filters, or when I insert the 'toDate' parameter, otherwise, when both parameters are null, the datagrid won't display any data.

I've read another similar question to this one, but it didn't solve my problem:
[A single sql query which can handle both null or valued date range in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520745/a-single-sql-query-which-can-handle-both-null-or-valued-date-range-in-sql-server)

Also, I've used other types of filters that seem to work normally even with null parameters.

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function doSearch(){
    $('#tt').datagrid('load',{
        fromDate: $('#fromDate').val(),
        toDate: $('#toDate').val(),          
    });
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
 <table id="tt" class="easyui-datagrid" style="width:1000px;height:450px"
 url="datagrid24_getdata.php" sortName="id" sortOrder="asc"
 title="Search" iconCls="icon-search" toolbar="#tb" 
 rownumbers="true" pagination="true">
 <thead>
 <tr>
       <th field="id" width="50" sortable="true">ID</th>
       <th field="userName" width="250" sortable="true">Name</th>
       <th field="date" width="100" sortable="true">Date</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
</table>
<div id="tb" style="padding:3px">
<span> Insert filter Parameters:</span>
<!-- DATE RANGE FILTER -->
<input id="fromDate" type="date" style="line-height:26px;border:1px solid #ccc">
<input id="toDate" type="date" style="line-height:26px;border:1px solid #ccc">

<a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" plain="true" onclick="doSearch()">Search</a>
</div>
```

My PHP datagrid24_getdata.php :

```
<?php
include 'conectionbd.php';

$page = isset($_POST['page']) ? intval($_POST['page']) : 1;
$rows = isset($_POST['rows']) ? intval($_POST['rows']) : 10;
$sort = isset($_POST['sort']) ? strval($_POST['sort']) : 'id';
$order = isset($_POST['order']) ? strval($_POST['order']) : 'asc';
$offset = ($page-1)*$rows;
$result = array();

//HERE WE FETCH THE VALUES FROM THE FILTER INPUTS
$fromDate= isset($_POST['fromDate']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fromDate']) : '';
$toDate= isset($_POST['toDate']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['toDate']) : '';

//THIS IS THE SQL QUERY I USE FOR THE DATE RANGE FILTER
$where = "date BETWEEN '$fromDate%' AND '$toDate%'";


$rs = mysql_query("select count(*) from table where " . $where);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($rs);
$result["total"] = $row[0];

$rs = mysql_query("select * from table where " . $where . " order by $sort $order limit $offset,$rows");

$items = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($rs)){
array_push($items, $row);
}
$result["rows"] = $items;

echo json_encode($result);?>
```

I'd really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this (I don't know PHP that well, so the syntax to check for date values being null will probably need to be corrected):

```
//THIS IS THE SQL QUERY I USE FOR THE DATE RANGE FILTER
$where = '';
// check if both the dates are not null
if ($fromDate != null && $toDate != null) {
    $where = "where date BETWEEN '$fromDate%' AND '$toDate%'";
} else if ($fromDate != null) {
    $where = "where date >= '$fromDate%'";
} else if ($toDate != null) {
    $where = "where date <= '$toDate%'"; 
}


$rs = mysql_query("select count(*) from table " . $where);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
I didn't know how to apply the IF condition properly. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to handle date conditions:

```
$where = '';
if (!empty($fromDate) && !empty($toDate)) {
   $where = "date BETWEEN '$fromDate%' AND '$toDate%'";
} else if(!empty($fromDate)) {
   $where = "date >= '$fromDate%'";
} else if(!empty($toDate)) {
   $where = "date <= '$toDate%'";
}
```